# Streaming videos from a Java backend

Tags: java, html, video, ffmpeg, streaming

I was wondering how most multimedia Java shops handle video streaming. Say I want to build a website that has a page that uses the HTML5 video player like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ... content up here

        <video width="500" height="500" controls="controls" src="path/to/video.mp4" />

        ... more content down here
</html>
```

Say the URL for this page is `http://myapp.example.org/video`. When HTTP requests for the `/video` path reach the `myappp.example.org` servers, I guess I have a few options:

- Route the request to a web app server (Tomcat/Jetty), and try to figure out how to stream the `video.mp4` video directly off that server using pure Java; or
- Route the request to a media server, and somehow stream `video.mp4` from that media server directly back to the client; or

  - On this end I've heard of servers like Red5 or Wowza
- Route the request to a media server (again, Red5/Wowza), and somehow stream `video.mp4` *through* the web app server acting as a middleman

There may be other options that I'm aware of (in which case, **what are they???**). My questtion:

**How is A/V streaming typically handled from behind a Java backend?**

Comment: why is a java back end diff from anything else. It returns an i-frame / div for the player.

Comment: Thanks @RobertRowntree (+1) - however, you are thinking of just the *client-side*. I'm talking about the server-side.

Answer (score 2):

go to any big media site like new york times and debug their player...

for example front page of NYT has video links in lower left side, a wrapped player...

rip it apart and watch it play the media which is separate from the markup of the hosted page.

```
<div class="videoOverlayDiv" id="1399731372442_nytd_vid_player_1399731372442_nytd_vid_player-posterImageContainer" style="cursor: pointer; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><img src="http://graphics8.nytimes.com/images/2014/05/09/multimedia/0511billcunningham/0511billcunningham-videoSmall.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"></div>
```

--EDIT--
Most media sites use a 2-step process in the player UI.

1. Show an iframe/div  with player controls wrapping a specific CID from the media catalog and wait for a control event like PLAY
2. on Play , JS will request a stream and JS player will start.PLAY on the stream

If so, then assume your question for req. #2 is "How can my java backend handle the stream in req #2 ?"

Well here the answer is that Java should be irrelevant because with any normal back-end like apache2/nginx, your 2nd data request for the media CID can include an HTTP Header that will tell any server like at S3 to encode the response so the media is stream-suitable and so the JS client can just play it... Details on that below

```
0000: GET /09d82830-ec2d-40b4-bb14-944728550685/9e896164-95a0-4f62-ae6
0040: b-4b55b2aef006-20140508152306.flac HTTP/1.1
006d: User-Agent: curl/7.28.1-DEV
008a: Host: files.parse.com
00a1: Accept: */*
00ae: Accept-Encoding: chunke    0000: GET /09d82830-ec2d-40b4-bb14-944728550685/9e896164-95a0-4f62-ae6
0040: b-4b55b2aef006-20140508152306.flac HTTP/1.1
006d: User-Agent: curl/7.28.1-DEV
008a: Host: files.parse.com
00a1: Accept: */*
00ae: Accept-Encoding: chunked
00c8: 
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 78 bytes (0x4e)
0000: x-amz-id-2: BuOgfHtRGjdrHeFaVhz9a4bhJ+LYnvUWxa0dYbxkxe7XL5UUm86F
0040: Z1qIosQXhXan
<= Recv header, 36 bytes (0x24)
0000: x-amz-request-id: B5FEA3C5231DC8A7
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Sun, 11 May 2014 17:03:12 GMT
<= Recv header, 46 bytes (0x2e)
0000: Last-Modified: Thu, 08 May 2014 22:23:14 GMT
<= Recv header, 52 bytes (0x34)
0000: x-amz-version-id: CvsKD0cAtBt9KrDqTdFwXxt.JMcBZ.pF
<= Recv header, 42 bytes (0x2a)
0000: ETag: "03e492b2d4c3518e6d09a3a37c61565e"
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Accept-Ranges: bytes
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Content-Type: image/*
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Content-Length: 87357
<= Recv header, 18 bytes (0x12)
0000: Server: AmazonS3
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 1064 bytes (0x428)
0000: fLaC..."...........b ...&.G..-.....J...#.O...&....reference libF
0040: LAC 1.2 20070917..........L...............5....y..i.(...........
0080: ...........................................d.......8...b....`...
00c0: ....UUUUUP.q..@..(.....A.0(.....AaP.|....I........@..XT.1... .H<
0100: :......(.....@ .......A$..].....;)B...=......(q..m...()P.P`.(H..
0140: ....(...U..=..Fyc,8W..d..{.....0n..$.......-6...(.m+.>....?.e...
0180: b>...|I)Xh...Q....%!.?J@.B1\*r...<.n..Gh...O.3.../..iS'.fX..o.(.
01c0: .&Xq&...{V..!..q....bR$.iVN3.E.I...".._.ED"I.>$.....@X...p@...
0200: L.#..........Cb6.E6...Wku..V.)......:o..g...SQ....R...#D....c.D
0240: ...hr.0.3>...:.,`....A..5.D..T..$.......m.......|.E.,f/..C.i.#..
0280: q.};...>.R.....].!..=/....=b.....%(.ds.....p.....1+...c...rp.[..
02c0: BQ'. ..H8....D0.&GBr.a}!.e&..}..*.f.._..e..K..,....f......X..\.[
0300: eK$.J....t..V%C.l.$n8P..^...T..h.*......Q....#...@..[Zv..(.... 
0340: ....J.;/..T.....dc..G...T.v...Q......N....C&[......L.N.!{... .KJ
0380: 7Z.. .[..}5.v,Q)#..@w...d....U..).[r...r.......E>.!..JsH!;.,./..
03c0: .E.\.L........../..+..F.A....9C..d....5.bso.q.j.HL...........r..
0400: 9....|.....dFk.e..F......=.....M6V..b'..
<= Recv data, 1460 bytes (0x5b4)
0000: sx%..1....>.Cu, S05>..K.f.Mz.g]..t:i..Z.=.&\......X........KK...
0040: .d.j..|q'7.<..U\$o.2....K..b.ZVn';L.RO.C....!..A&..&n.?B.......
0080: ..\g.."....%.O....p..}.Uf....xvIr..=ba_..t..0.L-...+h.........i.
00c0: WwD.4...Q)....4c.7.zN....._9..c..."...F.*.Jq.....]...e*...).$.P.
0100: ...Us.....6.........'.t......(J....:.....92..B.Y5..y8.:....!\..D
0140: ...;$...>L..4...L.....s...E..4k.T...}.g..R.m.Q.a.4.7I.x....O....
0180: ..(....:T..r........./,.$i......|........0.....7..f."......y].Md
00c8: 
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 78 bytes (0x4e)
0000: x-amz-id-2: BuOgfHtRGjdrHeFaVhz9a4bhJ+LYnvUWxa0dYbxkxe7XL5UUm86F
0040: Z1qIosQXhXan
<= Recv header, 36 bytes (0x24)
0000: x-amz-request-id: B5FEA3C5231DC8A7
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Sun, 11 May 2014 17:03:12 GMT
<= Recv header, 46 bytes (0x2e)
0000: Last-Modified: Thu, 08 May 2014 22:23:14 GMT
<= Recv header, 52 bytes (0x34)
0000: x-amz-version-id: CvsKD0cAtBt9KrDqTdFwXxt.JMcBZ.pF
<= Recv header, 42 bytes (0x2a)
0000: ETag: "03e492b2d4c3518e6d09a3a37c61565e"
<= Recv header, 22 bytes (0x16)
0000: Accept-Ranges: bytes
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Content-Type: image/*
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: Content-Length: 87357
<= Recv header, 18 bytes (0x12)
0000: Server: AmazonS3
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 1064 bytes (0x428)
0000: fLaC..."...........b ...&.G..-.....J...#.O...&....reference libF
0040: LAC 1.2 20070917..........L...............5....y..i.(...........
0080: ...........................................d.......8...b....`...
00c0: ....UUUUUP.q..@..(.....A.0(.....AaP.|....I........@..XT.1... .H<
0100: :......(.....@ .......A$..].....;)B...=......(q..m...()P.P`.(H..
0140: ....(...U..=..Fyc,8W..d..{.....0n..$.......-6...(.m+.>....?.e...
0180: b>...|I)Xh...Q....%!.?J@.B1\*r...<.n..Gh...O.3.../..iS'.fX..o.(.
01c0: .&Xq&...{V..!..q....bR$.iVN3.E.I...".._.ED"I.>$.....@X...p@...
0200: L.#..........Cb6.E6...Wku..V.)......:o..g...SQ....R...#D....c.D
0240: ...hr.0.3>...:.,`....A..5.D..T..$.......m.......|.E.,f/..C.i.#..
0280: q.};...>.R.....].!..=/....=b.....%(.ds.....p.....1+...c...rp.[..
02c0: BQ'. ..H8....D0.&GBr.a}!.e&..}..*.f.._..e..K..,....f......X..\.[
0300: eK$.J....t..V%C.l.$n8P..^...T..h.*......Q....#...@..[Zv..(.... 
0340: ....J.;/..T.....dc..G...T.v...Q......N....C&[......L.N.!{... .KJ
0380: 7Z.. .[..}5.v,Q)#..@w...d....U..).[r...r.......E>.!..JsH!;.,./..
03c0: .E.\.L........../..+..F.A....9C..d....5.bso.q.j.HL...........r..
0400: 9....|.....dFk.e..F......=.....M6V..b'..
<= Recv data, 1460 bytes (0x5b4)
0000: sx%..1....>.Cu, S05>..K.f.Mz.g]..t:i..Z.=.&\......X........KK...
0040: .d.j..|q'7.<..U\$o.2....K..b.ZVn';L.RO.C....!..A&..&n.?B.......
0080: ..\g.."....%.O....p..}.Uf....xvIr..=ba_..t..0.L-...+h.........i.
00c0: WwD.4...Q)....4c.7.zN....._9..c..."...F.*.Jq.....]...e*...).$.P.
0100: ...Us.....6.........'.t......(J....:.....92..B.Y5..y8.:....!\..D
0140: ...;$...>L..4...L.....s...E..4k.T...}.g..R.m.Q.a.4.7I.x....O....
0180: ..(....:T..r........./,.$i......|........0.....7..f."......y].M
```

Note the "Accept-Encoding" in the request's header.

Also Note the std apache2/nginx response will be as you see - a streamed response with NO CONTENT-LENGTH header. Its a stream. First 2 chunks in stream are [1064, 1460] in length as you can see.

You can just make Http your friend and get a streamed response with just one Header in your request.

Comment: Thanks @Robert Rowntree (+1) - however my question is about what the Java backend needs to look like to make streaming possible. For example, if I was using Spring MVC, what would the `Controller` look like that handled the HTTP request for `/video`?